# Symbol value does not exist in someMethod

Tags: scala, selenium, playframework, scala-2.10, scalatest

This is my source code for testing:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
import org.scalatest.Matchers

import play.api.test.FakeApplication
import play.api.test.WithApplication

class FunctionalSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  def withDriver(f: FirefoxDriver => Unit) = {
    val driver = new FirefoxDriver
    try {
      new WithApplication(
        new FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = Map("application.secret" -> "secret"))) {
        f(driver)
      }
    } finally {
      driver.quit
    }
  }
}
```

It doesn't show any compile-error in Eclipse. But when I execute the `test` command it shows [a very long error message](http://pastebin.com/FkJJU7UR). This is the first line of the errors:

> symbol value f$1 does not exist in test.FunctionalSpec$$anon$1$delayedInit$body.apply

I tried to play around a bit by modifying the code as shown below:

```
  def withDriver(f: FirefoxDriver => Unit) = {
    val driver = new FirefoxDriver
    try {
      val g = f
      val driver2 = driver
      new WithApplication(
        new FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = Map("application.secret" -> "secret"))) {
        val h = g
        val driver3 = driver2
        h(driver3)
      }
    } finally {
      driver.quit
    }
  }
```

There are no errors thrown when I executed the `test` command. Any idea what's happening? Is there any limit of how deep a block of code can go in order to keep the identifiers recognised?

EDIT:
Using my modified code above results in [runtime-error](http://pastebin.com/a4VSgSuP). I added the code below:

```
"The admin" should "be able to login and logout correctly" in withDriver { implicit driver =>
  // Don't do anything yet.
}
```

This one is displayed in one line of the runtime-error messages:

> Cause: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: g$1

Any suggestion for a workaround?

**ADDITIONAL NOTE:**
All the codes above compile just fine. Neither Eclipse or `scalac` complain. All the errors above happen only when I do the `test` command from the Play command shell.

Comment: Could you provide whole stack trace? I suspect the testing framework to have a bug.

Comment: Hi Rado. Thanks for the reply. Actually I have provided the whole stack trace in the link stated above and not put them here because they are just simply _very long_. Let me put the links again here:

 - [Before the modification](http://pastebin.com/FkJJU7UR).
 - [After the modification](http://pastebin.com/a4VSgSuP).

Comment: may be related https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/issues/620

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but I would do two things:

1. Use Specs2 instead of ScalaTest
2. Rewrite your tests as described here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaFunctionalTest